# forward, backward buttons in android music player project

Tags: android, eclipse, button

I have a music player application that coded in Eclipse. App has buttons such as Start/Pause, Next song, Previous song, Mixer. I want to add forward and backward buttons, how may i do it with the easiest way?

Thanks all.

Comment: Forward\backward is a rewind forward\rewind backward?

Comment: forward means fast forward or forward the song??

Comment: forward the song in time..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To fast forward the song:

```
public void forwardSong() {
    if (mPlayer != null) {
        int currentPosition = mPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
        if (currentPosition + seekForwardTime <= mPlayer.getDuration()) {
            mPlayer.seekTo(currentPosition + seekForwardTime);
        } else {
            mPlayer.seekTo(mPlayer.getDuration());
        }
    }
}
```

To rewind the song:

```
public void rewindSong() {
    if (mPlayer != null) {
        int currentPosition = mPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
        if (currentPosition - seekBackwardTime >= 0) {
            mPlayer.seekTo(currentPosition - seekBackwardTime);
        } else {
            mPlayer.seekTo(0);
        }
    }
}
```

mPlayer is the object of MediaPlayer.

seekForwardTime and seekBackwardTime are two variable to forward or rewind the song for defined second..

```
private int seekForwardTime = 5 * 1000; // default 5 second
private int seekBackwardTime = 5 * 1000; // default 5 second
```

Hope this will help...

Comment: Is this code working??

Answer (score 2):

There's an easy tutorial for a music player in android hive http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-building-audio-player-tutorial/

As show in the link create a buttons for Forward and Backward and use the code as below

```
btForward.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // get current song position
                int currentPosition = mp.getCurrentPosition();
                // check if seekForward time is lesser than song duration
                if(currentPosition + seekForwardTime <= mp.getDuration()){
                    // forward song
                    mp.seekTo(currentPosition + seekForwardTime);
                }else{
                    // forward to end position
                    mp.seekTo(mp.getDuration());
                }
            }
        });
```

For Backward

```
btBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // get current song position
                int currentPosition = mp.getCurrentPosition();
                // check if seekBackward time is greater than 0 sec
                if(currentPosition - seekBackwardTime >= 0){
                    // forward song
                    mp.seekTo(currentPosition - seekBackwardTime);
                }else{
                    // backward to starting position
                    mp.seekTo(0);
                }

            }
        });
```